# Как сделать если регистрация успешно, скопировать содержание одного столбца таблицы в другой

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Здравствуйте! Как сделать если регистрация успешно, скопировать содержание одного столбца таблицы в другой? Например регистрация успешно, автоматический скопировать `users=>id` на `users=>url`

```
function register_user($register_data) {
    array_walk($register_data, 'array_sanitize');
    $register_data['password'] = md5($register_data['password']);

    $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($register_data)) . '`';
    $data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $register_data) . '\'';

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` ($fields) VALUES ($data)");
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';

if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $required_fields = array('username', 'password', 'password_again', 'first_name', 'email');
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
        if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true) {
            $errors[] = '<div id="result_x"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div><div id="error">Заполните все поля чтобы продолжить регистрацию.</div>';
                break 1;
        }
    }

    if (empty($errors) === true) {
        if (user_exists($_POST['username']) === true) {
            $errors[] = '<div id="result_x"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div><div id="error">К сожалению, имя пользователя <b>' . $_POST['username'] . '</b> уже используется.</div>';
        }
        if (preg_match("/\\s/", $_POST['username']) == true) {
            $errors[] = '<div id="result_x"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div><div id="error">Ваш имя пользователя не должно содержать пробелов.</div>';
        }
        if (strlen($_POST['password']) < 6) {
            $errors[] = '<div id="result_x"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div><div id="error">Ваш пароль должен быть не менее 6 символов.</div>';
        }
        if ($_POST['password'] !== $_POST['password_again']) {
            $errors[] = '<div id="result_x"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div><div id="error">Ваш пароли не совпадают.</div>';
        }
        if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
            $errors[] = '<div id="result_x"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div><div id="error">Действительный адрес электронной почты требуется.</div>';
        }
        if (email_exists($_POST['email']) === true) {
            $errors[] = '<div id="result_x"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div><div id="error">К сожалению, электронной почты <b>' . $_POST['email'] . '</b> уже используется.</div>';
        }
    }
}
?>
<?php
if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
    $register_data = array(
        'username'   => $_POST['username'],
        'password'   => $_POST['password'],
        'first_name' => $_POST['first_name'],
        'last_name'  => $_POST['last_name'],
        'email'      => $_POST['email']
    );

    register_user($register_data);
    echo '<div id="result_x"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div><div id="error">Вы были успешно зарегистрирован!</div>';
} else if (empty($errors) === false) {
    echo output_errors($errors);
}
?>
```

Comment: Вторым запросом обновить по `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, только в транзакцию не забыть обернуть. Либо при создании записи можно в php получить созданный id и обновить его вторым запросом без транзакций. Вот только зачем дублировать данные? Если необходимо строить url на основе id, то может это в коде делать?

Comment: @ВОРОН, Да мне нужно дублировать `users=>id` на `users=>url` пожалуйста если знаете помогите!?

Comment: Я же вам два примера привел. И совет: логика должна быть отдельно от представления. Т.е. если надо получить и отобразить ошибки, то сначала их получаете (хотя бы в массив какой-нить), а уже потом отображаете через цикл. В соседнем вопросе вам уже сказали про шаблонизатор - используйте его (либо smarty).

Comment: @ВОРОН, пожалуйста смотрите [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001939/copy-values-from-one-column-to-another-in-the-same-table). Смотрите я обновил вопрос и добавил функций.

Comment: Это не совсем то, что требуется вам. Вы сегодня поменяете у кого-нить url, а завтра из-за нового пользователя замените url у текущего. Поэтому надо будет добавить условие `WHERE id=...`, но тогда чем этот вариант будет отличаться от моего?

Comment: @ВОРОН, По-моему, это невозможно да? Чтобы `id=url`.

Answer (score 1):

В базе данных не надо ничего копировать. Это не бумажный классный журнал.

База данных - это **совершенно другой подход к хранению информации.** В частности, одним из самых важных правил является [**отсутствие дублирования**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0).

Comment: При этом ради удобства/скорости и т.д. применяют именно дублирование ) НФ хороши в теории, но на практике дела обстоят немного иначе

Comment: Да для скорости все-таки обычно индексы ставят, а не денормализируют.

Comment: @Etki индекс ведь не панацея. Нормализация, это хорошо в теории, но надо понимать, что теория и практика это разные вещи. Когда данные есть в 1 таблице и дублируются в другой, это может работать быстрее, чем когда надо соединить 2 таблицы. При этом производительность чаще более критична, чем место на диске

Comment: Еще раз: то, что все денормализуют сплошь и рядом ради оптимизации скорости - это миф.

Comment: @Etki, не все, не сплошь и рядом, но иногда же встречается. Особенно тормоза нормализации будут чувствоваться, когда надо получить данные с нескольких огромных таблиц и немножко отсортировать. Без джойна или даже без сортировки все может и летать. И я бы говорил не "денормализируют", а не донормализируют., этого уже больше, чем умышленной денормализации. Вот вы много видели схем, выполненных в 5НФ?

Comment: Извините, мы упираемся в вопросы, сильно зависящие от мнения.